# How to create routes with multiple parameters?

Tags: angular

I need to create a route like this:

/company/:company_id/user/:user_id/create

How then use the Link router? Already tried:

```
[routerLink]="['company/user/create', empresa_id]"
[routerLink]="['company/:company_id/user/:user_id/create', empresa_id]"
```

But none of the right. I'm using Angular RC5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: `[routerLink]="['company', company_id, 'user', user_id, 'create']"`

each element of this array will be one part of the URL.

Answer (score 4):

It's quite unclear to me what your question is about but this might be what you want:

```
{ path: ':companyId/userId/create', component: 'UserComponent' }
```

```
[routerLink]="['/', company_id, user_id, '/create']"
```

Comment: This, but to match your desired URL of `/company/companyID/user/userID/create` you would define the path like: `{ path: 'company/:companyId/user/:userId/create` and your routerLink would look like: `[routerLink]='["/company", company_id, "user", user_id, "create"]'`.  See this plunker which does it with family: https://embed.plnkr.co/ih8KyOgPPxbFgh71BEHD/